# freeCodeCamp - Truncating a String. Exercise

Tags: javascript, string, function

I am trying to solve the problem Basic Algorithm Scripting: Truncate a String; but is not working properly...

```js
 let truncateString = (str, num) => {
   return (str.length <= num ? str : str.slice(0, num > 3 ? num - 3 : num) + '...');
 };


truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8);

// running tests
truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8) should return "A-tisket...".
truncateString("Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers", 11) should return "Peter Piper...".
// tests completed
```

Comment: You should be able to get rid of this `num > 3 ? num - 3 : num` and replace it with just `num`

Answer (score 2):

It's even simpler than your code - change your ternary operator a little:

```js
let truncateString = (str, num) => str.length > num ? str.slice(0, num) + "..." : str;

console.log(truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8));
console.log(truncateString("Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers", 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: (works)

```
let truncateString = (str, num) => {
   return (str.length <= num ? str : str.slice(0, num) + '...');
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let truncateString = (str, num) => {
       const x = str.length,
         y = num,
         min = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); 
       return str.slice(0, min) + (!(y-min) && '...');
    };
```